# Deserializing XML like response

Tags: java, xml, serialization

What would be the easiest way to deserialize a response like the following?

```
<maxlist>8</maxlist>
    <total>2</total>
    <biller1>
        <id>123</id>
        <alias>BIMA</alias>
        <name>Bima Insurance Agency</name>
        <wallet>bima</wallet>
        <category>insurance</category>
        <operation>gcash</operation>
        <fee>5</fee>
    </biller1>
    <biller2>
        <id>124</id>
        <alias>BILLER ALIAS</alias>
        <name>BILLER NAME</name>
        <wallet>BILLER CODE</wallet>
        <category>BILLER CATEGORY</category>
        <operation>gcash, parking or bancnet</operation>
        <fee>5</fee>
    </biller2>
```

This is all i get, as the response body for an http request. Is there an easy way to deserialize this using java?

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can. You can use JAXB for that .

Hope it will help you :

http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

Comment: Thanks for the help, but apparently, i can't. This response does not have a single parent element

Comment: What do you mean "This response does not have a single parent element " ? Please post whole response .